# Strange Crash issue as:- Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, crash-reports, event-dispatch-thread

I am developing an application in which a lot of operations are added in ASINetworkQueue.The operations are basically used for fetching the image from server and then in successful completion set the image in table view cell.

Everything is happening fine.I have a button a table view cell on which another view controller gets opened.

On that another view there is a cross button on which I pop that view controller.
Now when the cross button gets clicked sometimes the app gets crashed there, sometimes it gets crashes when comes back to the previous view and scrolling my table view.

When I see the crash logs I found that the following code comes in whatever the thread crashed.Sometime it is crashed thread2 ,sometime it is crashed thread 12, sometime it is crashed thread 6 but the code inside that thread is same which is shown below.

```
Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
Thread 11 Crashed:
0   Foundation                      0x357320b2 0x3569e000 + 606386
1   Foundation                      0x356add56 0x3569e000 + 64854
2   Foundation                      0x356adb94 0x3569e000 + 64404
3   Foundation                      0x35731f48 0x3569e000 + 606024
4   Foundation                      0x356add56 0x3569e000 + 64854
5   Foundation                      0x356adb94 0x3569e000 + 64404
6   Foundation                      0x35731ebc 0x3569e000 + 605884
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3698c9f6 0x36981000 + 47606
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3698f21e 0x36981000 + 57886
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3698cb70 0x36981000 + 47984
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3698d76c 0x36981000 + 51052
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32af91c8 0x32aef000 + 41416
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32af909c 0x32aef000 + 41116
```

I am stuck here as the crash log is not getting symolicated also  and also it is happening on some devices not on every device.

Please suggest me how to solve this strange crash issue.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.Please Please help me.

Comment: Will first figure out how to symbolicate the crash report, there's a ton of resources to help with that, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601048/iphone-app-crash-report-symbolication-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot talk to the exact technical reason that this is happening, but I had this error today. It occurred only on iPad 1 and it turned out to be related to trying to scale a huge image (which I thought was smaller). Reducing the size of the image removed the `com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority` error.

So it's probably memory related (particularly low memory).

Comment: How you fixed it then?

Comment: @spaleja if I recall correctly, I was working with an image that was being loaded from disk. Reducing the image (using Fireworks or Preview or whatever) removed the problem.