# iOS: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority

Tags: ios

I received crash from Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x8b2b0353

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
0  myApplication                  0x0028f0c4 Parse
1  ???                            0xffffffc9 
2  myApplic                       0x00291073 ukeylist_get_scan
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3aac9c5d _pthread_body + 140
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3aac9bcf _pthread_start + 102
```

My questions:

1. `com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority` means? (Maybe memory?)
2. Why second line is ???
3. How to fix this issue?

Thanks for your time to help me solve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange Crash issue as:- Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785914/strange-crash-issue-as-dispatch-queue-com-apple-root-default-overcommit-prior)

Comment: You can fix it by enabling NSZombieEnabled. Instructions are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 1):

The `com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority` is the name of the dispatch queue; I don't think that is anything of importance in this problem.

The second line is interesting, the address being very high.

Is `Parse` and `ukeylist_get_scan` methods that you have created or have introduced via a library?

The invalid kernel address you have is interesting; it is a address in a range I'd expect to be valid for code.  Normally you get a really low value such as 0x20 in crashes (which suggests a nil got in somewhere).

I think you have code which parses some input data with a Parse method, but your code is not robust to handle unexpected data.  So I recommend you write more defensive code on the Parse method (assuming it is one of your methods), and try writing some unit test code that passes in bad data.

If this is just the odd issue not seen again, there is not much you can do.  Otherwise you could just look at the overall pattern to see further clues; e.g. always same device, or always a certain OS version, or always a low-end device, etc.